# android Zooming and paning image with canvas drawing

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am working on android 2D graphics. My requirement is simple. I have to Zoom and panning around the image and i need to draw on particular palce(free hand drawing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello   [see](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-6-implementing-the-pinch-zoom-gesture/1847)  this its exactly as per your requirement..:):) good luck

Comment: thanks for reply @Kalpesh.. But i nned to draw on image as well as zoom in and zoom out.. is this possible?

Comment: @user1693954 thanks for kind words...you want to draw with any object (like pencil) or with finger??

Comment: And yes that is also possible..just take care of co-ordinates nd u will get result..Happy Zooming :):)